# Status page from prometheus alerts?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Is there anyway we can create a status page with data from prometheus alerts? Status pages should be something similar to status.io page but the data should be from prometheus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a lot of tools but couldn't find any which suits my requirements. For anyone looking for a simple solution, the best bet is Prometheus api.

Prometheus api will be like

```
http://prometheus-weburl/prometheus/api/v1/query?query=ALERTS{alertname="InstanceDown"}
```

Traversing through the output json for return values can be used to update innerHTML if used with JavaScript.